# How do I use InstanceScope.HttpSession in StructureMap?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm trying to use StructureMap's InstanceScope.HttpSession feature and I'm running into problems.  I have the following method I'm using for testing:

```
public static class StructureMapTest {
    public static T Get<T>() {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry(new RepositoryRegistry()));
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

My RepositoryRegistry class looks like this:

```
public class RepositoryRegistry : Registry {
    public RepositoryRegistry() {
        ForRequestedType<IClientRepository>()
            .CacheBy(InstanceScope.HttpSession)
            .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<ClientRepository>();
    }
}
```

So in my client code (ASP.NET MVC controller) I do something like the following:

```
public ActionResult InjectionTest() {
    return Content(DataProvider.Clients.CreatedDate.ToString());
}
```

And every time I call this controller even from the same session, I get a new instance every time.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try my answer? I haven't have this trouble, and the main difference is that my configuration is on the global.asax

Answer (score 1):

Move the ObjectFactory.Configure to the global asax. You are not supposed to keep reconfiguring structuremap each time an object is requested.